# UICollectionViewLayout Examples

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Can anybody point me in the right direction to how I could use UICollectionViewLayout to create an interface similar to the Pinterest column layout?

I tried searching online, but it looks like there are not many examples out there yet.

Answer (score 14):

The 1000memories "Quilt" view is pinterest-like and open source: http://blog.1000memories.com/168-opensourcing-quilt, and you can dig through that to see how it works.

If you're looking for a more conceptual overview, here's the basic idea of what you're going to want to do. The easiest thing by far, if you just need a Pinterest-style layout, is to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. You get a lot of layout help from this class, and Pinterest style is within its capabilities.  You only need to override one method.

Set up a normal UICollectionView using UICollectionViewFlow layout.  A quick way to do this is:

- Drag a UIViewController onto a storyboard, drop a UICollectionView on that. Set the classes to match your custom classes, etc. You can use a delegate and create a delegate class here but strictly speaking that is not necessary to achieve JUST the Pinterest flow layout (you will almost definitely want to break the selection responsibility stuff into a delegate class in reality though).
- Stub out a data source. Implementing the data source protocol for UICollectionView (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is trivially simple. Make sure you set a reuse identifier on your UICollectionViewCell. You need:

  1. `(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView`

     - just return 1 for now;
  2. `(NSInteteger)collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`

     - hardcode a number for now, make it 20.
  3. – `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

     - This is one of the places where subclassing the flow layout's gonna do you a favor. All you really need to do here is call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` with the index path. If you added a UIImageView or some labels to the cell, this would be a great place to actually assign the image, text, etc.
- In the viewController's `viewDidLoad` instantiate a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set the UICollectionView's datasource to yours and layout to flowlayout. Remember, this class is a subclass of `UICollectionViewViewController`.

  ```
  self.collectionView.dataSource = [[YourDataSource alloc] init];
  self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  ```

Ok. At this point you should be able to run your app and see some stuff on the screen. This is a whirlwind overview. If you need more details about how to set up ViewControllers and so on there's tons of stuff available about that.

Now comes the important part, Pinterest-izing the flow layout.

First, add a new class that is a subclass of UIViewControllerFlowLayout. Change your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` to instantiate this class and assign as the `UICollectionView`'s `collectionViewLayout`.

The method you are going to need to implement is `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`.

Here's the thing: The superclass is going to do almost all the work for you.  Your code is going to look something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]; 
    [attributes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id attr, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    float newYCoord = [calculationMethodYouHaveToWriteFor:attr.frame];
    attr.frame = CGRectMake(attr.frame.origin.x, newYCoord, attr.size.width, attr.size.height];
}];

}
```

Pinterest uses fixed-width columns, all you need to do in your calculation method is figure out what column you are in (`attr.origin.x / _columnWidth), and look up the total height in that column from the ivar you've been saving it in.  Don't forget to add it to the new object's height and save it back for the next pass.

The flow layout superclass handles: making cells, determining which cells are visible, figuring out the contents size, figuring out the arrangement of the rows in the x direction, assigning index paths to cells.  Lots of junk.  And overriding that one method lets you fiddle with the y-pos to your heart's desire.

Comment: Im getting an array of zero at this point     NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]; 
. My collection views shows up if I don't override collectionViewLayout

Answer (score 7):

Heres two from github

https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo

https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout

I've used a modified version of Waterfall in a project now, and I'm investigating JSPint now.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a custom uicollectionviewlayout which is used in my personal project. Here is the link. Hope it helps.

https://github.com/johnny0614/YJZAlbumCollectionViewLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can get anything you want from here:
https://github.com/ParsifalC/CPCollectionViewKit
For example(Both these two layouts are custom UICollectionViewLayout):

[image: TransitionLayout]